# How to set tooltip of Bootstrap Select plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set the tooltip of bootstrap select control but still don't find a way.

My scenario is I have select control with no label (because of the page design). So, whatever the item was selected and when user hover on it, I would like to display "Inventory Items" (label of my select control).

I tried to set the title attribute of options items but it set the text of the item instead of chaging. Bootstrap select plugin render options as buttons I think and I don't know how to set them.

```
Here is my "Fiddle" http://jsfiddle.net/tslin306/u2gaorLu/
```

FYI: Because of the requirement, I cannot use bootstrap tooltip.

Please advice,
Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Please Include [bootstrap-tooltip.js](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js)

after that please use The Following Javascript in your page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddlPostCircle").tooltip({
        placement: 'right' /*Whatever you like*/
    });
});
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ytpAy/74/) <-- thanks to praveen for this fiddle

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I cannot use bootstrap tooltip :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want 'inventory item' as tooltip specify the size of total options add `size="4"` in your fiddle

```
<div style='padding:20px'>
    <select id="ddlPostCircle" class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow" data-width="150px"title="inventory items" size="4">
        <option value='1'>Item 1</option>
        <option value='2' >Item 2</option>
        <option value='3'>Item 3</option>
        <option value='4'>Item 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It doesn't work after I choose an item. If I select "item 1", tooltip is showing "item 1" where I still want to show "Inventory Items".

Comment: You can add title="inventory items" in each options so every option will show this tooltip. but you cant see the selected item or you can use **Farveen Hassan's** answer that show tooltip but show 'item1' onload in select box

Comment: I already tried like that. But due to the documentation from this page http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/#content_options, title are used to set the default text of the select picker. You can see my updated fiddle with title attribute on individual options here: http://jsfiddle.net/tslin306/u2gaorLu/4/